# UL tag does not show same css as OL

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists, unordered

I have this javascript accordion (.heading) and I'm trying to apply it to an unordered list (the first "ul" tag). What's weird is that the formatting (mostly focused on the hover color) works on an ordered list, just not on the "ul" tag.

HTML

```
<h3><a></a></h3>
  <div>
    <ul>
    <li class="heading"></li>
    <ul class="content">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>

        </ul>   
    <li></li>   
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.heading {
margin: 1px;
color: black;
padding: 3px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
font-weight: bold;
}

.heading:hover{
margin: 1px;
color: black;
padding: 3px 10px;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
font-weight: bold;
background:#cccccc
}

.content {
padding: 5px 10px;
}
p { padding: 5px 0; }
```

Thank you for any help.

EDIT:

This is the javascript script I have inputted in the

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery(".content").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  jQuery(".heading").click(function()
  {
    jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: your html is wrong with the marking. Try validated by http://validator.w3.org and see the error

Comment: I apologize, I'm only including the segment of content with the actual problem. The rest of the site is functional. Unless I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: Make a JsFiddle so we can see it

Comment: Both ol and ul perform the same for me based off what you've provided. http://jsfiddle.net/BEbH6/. Could the issue be javascript related?

Answer (score 1):

You have nested your lists incorrectly. A nested list needs to be inside a `li` element, not as a direct child of the first `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

Your marking the HTML is wrong, even if it is "functional" for you.

Read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML

Study from this link:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/ul.html

This link says this:

> **Permitted contents**
>
> zero or more li elements

In other words, other elements is not allowed directly inside `<UL>` or `<OL>` unless the `<LI>`.

You must add the `<UL class="content">` (or `<OL class="content">`) inside another `<LI>`.

To better understand you, what you should do is something like this:

```
<style>
li.heading {
    margin: 1px;
    color: black;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li.heading:hover{
    margin: 1px;
    color: black;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
    background:#cccccc;
}

li.content ul {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
</style>

<ul>
<li class="heading"></li>
<li class="content">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. But why does the hover work when using <ol> and not when using <ul>?

Comment: @user3242175 I added an example for you to understand what I meant. Good luck!